# Two subgroups $N,H$ if $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $NH\trianglelefteq G$ does that imply $H\trianglelefteq G$? If not give counter example

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $H\leq G$, such that $NH \trianglelefteq  G$ is it true that $H\trianglelefteq  G$?

I guess it is true but am not sure, we know for any $x$ we have
$$NH = x^{-1}NHx = x^{-1}Nxx^{-1}Hx = N x^{-1}Hx$$
But that does not mean we can cancel $N$ since it could be the case where $n_1h_1 = n_2 x^{-1}h_2x\Rightarrow n_2^{-1}n_1 h_1 = x^{-1}h_2x$ am not sure how to complete.

Thanks.

Comment: You can find a counterexample in $S_3$.

Comment: aha the group generated by (123) normal if we consider the product <(123)><(12)> is the whole group which is normal but that does not imply <(12)> normal. Thanks

Comment: Any example where $NH$ is not the whole group? If you know one please post as an answer so I accept it.

Comment: Well, you could sort of trivially create an example where $NH$ is not the whole group by taking essentially the same example, but in $S_3 \times C_2$, or in $S_3 \times \mathbb{Z}$, etc.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thats smart, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next smallest example is one where $N,H,NH,G$ are all distinct subgroups of $G$.

Consider $G=D_{2\cdot 4}=\langle r,\bar{r}\mid r^4=r\bar{r}r\bar{r}=\bar{r}^2=1\rangle$ the dihedral group of order $8$.  Let $N=\{1,r^2\}$, $H=\{1,\bar{r}\}$.
Then it is easy to check:

- $N\lhd G$;
- $H<G$ is not normal;
- $NH\lhd G$.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @user10354138, we take $S_3=\{1,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$ then $\langle(123)\rangle \langle (12)\rangle = S_3 \trianglelefteq S_3$ but $\langle (12)\rangle$ not normal.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for delimiters (here, "subgroup generated by"), not `<` and `>`, which are relational symbols.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I tried \leftangle which did not work that why it is \langle. Thanks!